# How to access row id in javascript and achieve expand/collapse of multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating rows using Perl CGI.It looks something like this:

```
 my @header_columns = ("Dealer1","Dealer2","Dealer3");
 my $var =0;
 my $joinData=""; #or previous rows
 foreach my $val(@header_columns)
 {
    $var++;
    $joinData = join("",$pars->{cgi}->th({-colspan=>'2',-id=>'row1',-align=>'left',-style=>"border-left:1px solid black},
    $cgi->button({-id =>$var,
                  -value=>'+',
                  -onClick=>"collapsible($var);"
                  }),
    $cgi->span({-style=>"weight:bold; align:center;"},$val)));
   $joinHTMLdatarows= join('',$joinHTMLdatarows,$pars->{cgi}->Tr({class=>"cssRow"},join("",$joinData)));
}
```

Now I am generating details columns

```
 for(my $i=0; $i<5;i++)
 {
    $joinData=join("",$joinData,$pars->{cgi}->th({-colspan=>'1'},"something"));
 }
 $joinHTMLdatarows= join('',$joinHTMLdatarows,$pars->{cgi}->Tr({class=>"cssRow"},join("",$joinData)));
```

My JS function

```
function collapsible(rowid)
{
   var elem =  document.getElementById(rowid);
   if(elem.value=='+')
   {
      elem.value='-';
      elem.style.display="";
   }
   else
   {
     elem.value='+';
     elem.style.display="none";
   }
```

Basically I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image: HereiswhatIwant]

As you can see I want specific row ids for javascript function to be passed as parameters,For example on clicking `+` on `Dealer1`,the rows should expand and populate and I want to get these row IDs as parameters ,but I can't seem to get pass that,is there a way around this?

Comment: _"but I can't seem to get that "_ -- You will need to explain what that means.  Also, have you examined the generated HTML at the client?  You should be able to see exactly what is happening and examine each generated `onclick` to see what is actually being sent to the browser.  You HAVE done that already right?  If not, you need to step back and look at some tutorials on debugging web applications.

Comment: I can't seem to pass/read the rowID (in this case it's `row1` ) to my JS function.getting it as undefined

Comment: Have you stepped through the Perl code to see what is happening?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with Perl code,it's generating the HTML rows as expected. In order to hide/expand rows I guess I just need to pass/read rowID's on `onClick` event

Comment: In HTML 4, `id` attributes need to start with a letter

Comment: @MattJacob Thanks.But I think i need to pass the rowID not button ID

Comment: You do. But it would be easier to pass nothing and traverse up to the row.

Comment: @MattJacob How do you accomplish that?

Comment: All the rows have the same id - "row1" - which isn't going to help. Should that be `"row$var"` instead?

Comment: @ChrisTurner ofcourse,but my problem is how to access that `row$var` in JS

Comment: `$var` won't exist in your JS as it's a Perl variable. You should remove the ugly and very outdated Perl code from the question as it's irrelevant and put in the HTML instead.

Comment: Still doesn't get me what i want

Comment: I would give each row a unique ID, then in your code you can put something like -onClick=>"collapsible($var, $rowID);`...then the "collapsible" function can accept a second parameter containing the row ID, and use that to show/hide the correct row. Right now your Javascript, if it works at all, will hide the button and not the row